# Spark Streaming Kafka Integration Issue

Tags: docker, apache-spark, apache-kafka

I am using docker for my sample Spark + Kafka project in windows machine. I am facing

```
Failed to find data source: kafka. Please deploy the application as per the deploym ent section of "Structured Streaming + Kafka Integration Guide".;
```

build.sbt

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(
    inThisBuild(List(
      version := "0.1.0",
      scalaVersion := "2.12.2",
      assemblyJarName in assembly := "sparktest.jar"
)),
    name := "sparktest",
    libraryDependencies ++= List(
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-core" % "2.4.0",
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql" % "2.4.0",
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "2.4.0",
      "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % "2.4.0" % "provided",
      "org.apache.kafka" %% "kafka" % "2.1.0",
      "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5",
      "com.typesafe.scala-logging" %% "scala-logging" % "3.9.0"
    ),
      dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-databind" % "2.9.8",
      dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.core" % "jackson-core" % "2.9.8",
      dependencyOverrides += "com.fasterxml.jackson.module" % "jackson-module-scala_2.12" % "2.9.8")

assemblyMergeStrategy in assembly := {
  case PathList("META-INF", xs@_*) => MergeStrategy.discard
  case x => MergeStrategy.first
}
```

Code

```
val inputStreamDF = spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "kafka:9092")
                           .option("subscribe", "test1")
                           .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
                           .load()
```

Has anyone faced similar issue, how did you resolve?

Comment: Can you try removing "provided" in the sbt file for the library spark-sql-kafka-0-10?

Comment: @mike, I removed provided but still same error